# Find max number in array

Tags: java

I am doing this JAVA homework for school and I have this task, but I can't find a beginner explanation on the web.

So I have to print out the biggest number in this array, please help...

```
int[] mas = {12, 2135, -354, 4353, -1312, 4636, 1312, 3, 51};
```

Comment: have you tried any attempt ?

Comment: You need a tutorial, or to speak with your teacher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Commons Lang (to convert) + Collections (to min/max)

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

import org.apache.commons.lang.ArrayUtils;

public class MinMaxValue {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[] a = {'3', '5', '1', '4', '2'};

        List b = Arrays.asList(ArrayUtils.toObject(a));

        System.out.println(Collections.min(b));
        System.out.println(Collections.max(b));
   }
```

Comment: you are welcome don't forget to accept my solution and click up to in the left to my answer @KarlisBlumanis

Comment: @Fureeish okey no problem

Answer (score 1):

Shortest solution:

```
int[] mas = {12, 2135, -354, 4353, -1312, 4636, 1312, 3, 51};
int max = Arrays.stream(mas).max().orElse(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort(default with natural order: min to max) could be used and grab last element from array for max (or first for min).

```
  int[] a = {12, 2135, -354, 4353, -1312, 4636, 1312, 3, 51};
  Arrays.sort(a);
  int max = a[a.length-1]; \\4636
  int min = a[0]; \\-1312
```